# Is There A Way To Toggle Vim Into A Read-only Mode? I Am Not Talking About Opening In That Mode But Something Like Safe Mode

Tags: vim

I want to leave a note always open in corner of the screen to capture my thoughts but i  want to make sure I didn't accidentally make that windows active and change something. Is there a way  to make it read-only on a keystroke?

Answer (score 4):

You can turn modifiable off with:

```
:set nomodifiable
```

or

```
:set noma
```

and turn it back on with

```
:set modifiable
```

or

```
:set ma
```